# Why IBAction and IBOutlet are Invisible

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, storyboard

Why the `IBOutlet` and `IBAction` are not visible in `ViewController` if i do like this

1. declare `IBOutlet` and `IBAction` in .h file
2. Go to `main.storyboard`
3. check for these `IBoutlet` and `IBactions` in viewcontroller
   in .nib / .xib file its visible then why its not visible in storyboard
   I know this is a very simple question but i want to know the reason.

   **Edit**
   do the same process for a new project, after that its working fine for both. I don't think its an issue or what.

Comment: Can you add an image ? Also check the class of viewcontroller in the storyboard.

Comment: Can you post your .h file?

Comment: can i know where you are trying to see these outlets.. Are you not able to see in file inspector.. ?

Comment: Did you find out what was the problem? Remember to upvote and accept the correct answer if you did :-)

Comment: NO i don't know what is the problem, simply created another project and repeat the same steps. After that its working fine in both i don't know what is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to set the class of your view controller to your custom class. Find your class in the drop-down field:

[image: identity inspector]

Answer (score 1):

declare your custom viewcontroller in storyboard identifier

[image]

then you can drag the link to your viewcontroller .m file area

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: you can see IBOutlets here]

here you can see all IBOutlets connected to each object thank you..

Answer (score 0):

did you set same View Controller class Name (in which you set all IBOutlet and IBAction) to  identity inspector of ViewController in MainStoryboard

[image]